# Assume $X_i$ are i.i.d, from Poisson$(\lambda)$ distribution for some $\lambda >0$, Show $\sqrt{n}(1/\bar{X}-1/\lambda)\to_D N(0,\sigma_{\lambda}^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

> Assume $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d, from Poisson$(\lambda)$ distribution for some $\lambda >0$, Show that $\sigma_{\lambda}^2$ $\sqrt{n}(1/\bar{X}-1/\lambda)\to_D N(0,\sigma_{\lambda}^2)$, then compute $\sigma_{\lambda}^2$

I see this already looks similar to the statement about Central limit theorem, I thought I would solve by letting $Y_i=\frac{1}{X_i}$, however I would only know that $E(Y)\geq \frac{1}{\lambda}$

Comment: A problem with considering $E[Y_i]$ is that it is undefined (or infinite) as there is probability $e^{-\lambda}>0$ that $X_i=0$.  Meanwhile  $P(\bar X=0) =e^{-n\lambda}$ which is also positive but at least heads towards $0$ as $n$ increases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the CLT tells you
$$\sqrt n (\bar X-\lambda)\rightarrow_d N(0,\lambda).$$

Now use the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to find the asymptotic distribution of

$$\sqrt n (g(\bar X)-g(\lambda))$$

taking $g:t\rightarrow 1/t$.

---

Update: Alternatively, write

$$\sqrt n \left(\frac{1}{\bar X}-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda \bar X}\right)\sqrt n (\bar X-\lambda),$$

and the weak law of large numbers tells us $\bar X\rightarrow_p \lambda.$ Now use [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

Comment: ( just for completeness, for the second approach you need also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem )

Comment: @Thomas Repeated use of Slutsky's should suffice, no? Only products and quotients are involved.

Comment: Of course, continuous mapping theorem implies Slutsky's

Comment: Of course looking at the proofs delta method, slutsky and continuous mapping can be proven exploting the other. I do not have clear all the relationships at the moment. But I see that if $X_n \rightarrow_p K$ than $1/X_n \rightarrow_p 1/K$ can be either derived by the statement of the continuous mapping theorem, or by Slutsky.

Comment: But with Slutsky it is a bit involved no ? I would use for this the third statement of wikipedia with $X_n=1$ (the constant function), $Y_n=\overline X$ , so that $X_n/Y_n=1/\overline X \rightarrow 1/\lambda$.

Comment: @Thomas Yep, it just takes a few quick rounds of Slutsky

Comment: Perfect thx for the discussion :)